# CSS Slider skipping images and not working smoothly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Working on a CSS only slider, and have been having troubles with dynamically added images. I was able to solve most of my problems, but on some slide shows (seems to be random) the images do not play in order, and some are skipped over.

I have included a CodePen that replicated my exact issue: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPmEda

I am allowing for up to 15 images. After the images scroll through, the order is messed up. Sometimes I get the same image every other transition, but others seem totally random.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/7gZEY7tY9C4/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/ZMcLVBi9xx4/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/lZlfHGqx44Q/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/bviex5lwf3s/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/6LkxufmApSk/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/xFjAftU8lMY/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/qsEJGX4VqYU/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/dJVU4jXV1Q8/download" alt="">
    <img class="photo" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/3ytjETpQMNY/download" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.photo{
    position:absolute;
    animation:round 16s infinite;
    opacity:0;
}
@keyframes round{   
    25%{opacity:1;}
    40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(15){animation-delay:56s;}
img:nth-child(14){animation-delay:52s;}
img:nth-child(13){animation-delay:48s;}
img:nth-child(12){animation-delay:44s;}
img:nth-child(11){animation-delay:40s;}
img:nth-child(10){animation-delay:36s;}
img:nth-child(9){animation-delay:32s;}
img:nth-child(8){animation-delay:28s;}
img:nth-child(7){animation-delay:24s;}
img:nth-child(6){animation-delay:20s;}
img:nth-child(5){animation-delay:16s;}
img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:12s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:0s;}
```

Comment: `animation-delay` only applies the first time around.  It doesn't delay the animation on every iteration.

Comment: Is there a simple solution that you can think of for this? @DivineComedian

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?  I'm all for CSS-only solutions if possible, but I think this is not a good case for using only CSS.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using JavaScript, but it may be unavoidable in this case. Thank you for your advice @DivineComedian

Comment: @EricBellDesigns: using **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/r0zk9fke/)** is what I was able to produce, out of interest. And **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/r0zk9fke/1/)** with the _yoyo_ property.

Comment: @TahirAhmed That is a very nice solution! Unfortunately I am unable to add a script, due to extreme testing that will be involved. I do plan on using this for future projects, and I plan to use your solution. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: @EricBellDesigns: I understand. But yeah, do look into this tool. GSAP has been around for years and is a very useful suite of tools.